# CSS modules with SASS variables in media queries

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-modules

In my case, I'm using SASS variables for colors, font-size, and media-queries. I've created them in their own files and then imported to one single index.scss file. Then when I need to use in any .module.scss I just import at the top like:

`@import 'src/constants/index.scss';`

It is work just fine for colors, font-size...but when comes media queries, the variables are ignored.

works: `@media screen and (max-width: 740px)`

does not work: `@media screen and (max-width: $small)`

I even simplified them like so:

```
$small: 740px;
$medium: 1024px;
$large: 1100px;
```

then I've applied these variables in font-size and works fine, they just not works in media queries.

Why is that? Any help?

Cheers!

Comment: You need to be 3.2 or higher, check this: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32

Comment: Hi @Katie , thank you for your answer, but this article seems to be from 7 years ago hehehe... and as I can see here, my version is higher :)

Comment: Otherwise, it should work fine, so it is some other gotcha, try isolating the code and watch what CSS is generated.  Hope you find it!

Comment: Hi @Katie, just to let you know..after a few tests apparently the problem is with the name of the variable '$medium'... $small and $large works and when I change medium for _$test_  it works just fine. Maybe is a kind of reserved word? or is clashing with another variable or class?  I don't know..but at least a solution was found!

Comment: That was something I was wondering as well, if maybe there were reserved words, but on a cursory search found no documentation on the SASS website,  but there may be hidden ones :)  It is really the only explanation, because if it was clashing with another variable, such as in a framework, you should have still been able to override it locally.  Anyway, so glad you found it!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media (max-width: $small) {
  //code
}
```

Comment: you can try using breakpoints

$small: 768px;

//@include breakpoint(453px $small) {

}

Compiles to: 
//@media (min-width: 453px) and (max-width: 768px) {

}

Comment: the problem was the variable name as I explained above for Katie. Cheers!